# Pretty URL's with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I'm using jQuery to ajax a few items on my page. When I go to one of the pretty URL's that the htaccess file makes, it error's out. Here's the jQuery code I'm currently using:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "inc/file.php",
        success: function(result){
        $('#NavMoreInfo').html(result);
        navMoreInfoCloseButton();
        $(":not(#NavMoreInfo)").click(function() {
            $('#NavMoreInfo').slideUp(300);
        }); 
        },
        error: function(event, request){
            alert(request);
        }
```

Here's my htaccess file:

```
    DirectoryIndex master.php
    # Enable Rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^main/?$ master.php
    RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ master.php?page=$1
```

How can I crossDomain my jQuery AJAX? Or is it something in my htaccess that I need to change?
Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: what `errors out`? whats the `error`?

Comment: what is the question? redirects? or cross domain Ajax?

Comment: AJAX requests are exactly the same as regular HTTP requests, other than a header or two. Try hitting that url yourself in a browser and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See jquery ajax documentation, for crossdomain requests :

crossDomain(added 1.5)
Default: **false** for same-domain requests, **true** for cross-domain requests

If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.

UPDATE **

You need to provide the FULL url of the requested website . This includes http:// or https://

in your case **"http://www.mysite.com/inc/file.php"**

Comment: I added
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "http://www.mysite.com/inc/file.php",
To my jQuery script, and still nothing. I;ve been playing with that, and the json settings for a couple hours. Could you give me an example?
I read the doc as well, still no result. It's not my php file either. Probably something I'm missing..

Answer (score 0):

I had to add http:// infront of my URL. For some reason, having the http:// www... was not working.

Removing the www worked.

Thank you everyone for the help!